# why am I getting the following errors : In constructor 'B::B(int, int)': no matching function for call to 'A::A()'

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm getting errors and don't know what is wrong

I've tried leaving out the constructors.

i'm getting the following errors:

> In constructor 'B::B(int, int)': no matching function for call to 'A::A()'
>
> note candidates are:
>
> A::A(const A&)
>
> A::A(int, int)

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class A{
  public:
         int a;
         int b;
         A(int a1, int b1){
               a=a1; b = b1;
               }
  };

class B : public A {
  public:
         int c;
         int d;
         int e;
         B(int c1=10, int d1=20){
               c=c1; d=d1;
               e = a * b;
               }          
  void show(){
       cout <<"a = "<<a<<endl;
       cout <<"b = "<<b<<endl;
       cout <<"c = "<<c<<endl;
       cout <<"d = "<<d<<endl;
       cout <<"e = "<<e<<endl;
       }
  };

int main() {
  A a(2,2);
  B b;
  b.show();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you think would be the values of b.a and b.b?

Answer (score 6):

`B` inherits from `A` so it needs to construct an `A` but you don't have a default constructor for `A` nor do you explicitly call a constructor for `A` from `B`'s initialization list.

Something like this is what you need:

```
B(int c1=10, int d1=20) : A(c1, d1) {
               c=c1; d=d1;
               e = a * b;
               }
```

Or make `A` default constructible.

Also, you should be using the initialization list for `c`, `d`, and `e` as well, instead of assigning to the in the body of your constructor (though the optimizer will take care of it in this situation, it's better form to do it the right way all the time)

```
B(int c1=10, int d1=20) : A(c1, d1), c(c1), d(d1), e(a*b) {}
```